# Concept of relationships with death, destruction, oblivion, time, chaos and darkness/abyss what's their interlink/relationship with each other?

Tags: magic

What I want to know their interrelationship with each other. I want someone to kinda give me detail or summary if you will their with those concepts with each other. The thing is death, destruction, oblivion, time, chaos and darkness has some connections. By passing of time living beings die as death is destruction of all life. Destruction is that destroys all creation as and etc. As you can see they are kinda in relationship and interlinked between each other. But I have vague concept of knowledge about them so I wanted more details knowledge about it I hope you guys get what I'm trying to say.

Comment: Please note that just asking for ideas and opinion is what we call "primarily opinion-based" because there are no criteria and every somewhat reasonable opinion would be exactly equally valid - you can't compare opinions against each other. That's why this is a close-reason as the goal of StackExchange is to have questions where the answers can somewhat objectively rated against each other. Please [edit] your question to add some criteria and explain what you have so far and whether these are natural forces, magical properties, ... For the moment I am voting to temporarily pu tthis on hold.

Comment: This is way too broad a question. We are not going to write your essay for you.

Comment: Hegao, don't feel too bad about this question being closed, the philosophic question you asked probably ranks as the #1 most opinion-base and broad question ever to be asked on this site.  Honestly, people have been writing about and thinking about this very question for thousands of years.  If you're gonna dream, dream big!